# C# Mvc 3, custom routing class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, unity-container

How can i get the data from the routes before they are processed?

Like this, i got the following url:

```
localhost:1111/{eventid}/controller/method/id
```

The `{eventid}` will be available for almost all calls throughout the entire application. Now i need to get the `{eventid}` BEFORE my IOC unity resolver gets the controller. In the controller i got a dependency that is configured in unity like this:

```
container.RegisterType<UserIdent>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
{
     ...
     return GetUser(User.Identity.Name, Session["EventId"].ToString());
}));
```

So i need the `Session["EventId"]` to be set before unity resolves this.

So basicly i only need to see if the EventId is present in the routing values (before any calls to the dependency resolver is made) and if it is present create/update a new/the session with the id number.

2) Is there a better way to pass that id to unity then using a session with the event id? 
This will occur on every request that the user makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for using an Action Filter.

```
public class PopulateEventIdInSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{       
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {           
        object eventId = filterContext.ActionParameters["eventid"];
        if (eventId != null)
        {
            Session["EventId"] = (int)eventId;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is there a better way then using Sessions to pass the eventid to unity? Unity creates a new copy of it upon the request as shown above, can i pass the event id in any other way not involving a session?

Comment: I've thought about it and I can't think of a better way. It may be worth considering if there's a possibility to change the design so it doesn't need to be passed in on instantiation?

Answer (score 0):

You could try write Regex, which will parsed Url and set eventId in cookie or in session. 
This functionality you could implement in BeginRequest or in HttpModule.

As for me I would have written my own factory, which will create Users and not using unity as a solution.